# Java split function eliminating spaces

Tags: java, split, delimiter

I am trying to put strings into an array which have a space as a delimiter, it works great except for the first string has a space in front and so the first element in the array is "" instead of the first string.

```
    public static String[] loadMessage(String fileName)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    String[] s = null;
    File f = new File(fileName + ".txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(f);
    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        s = inFile.nextLine().split(" ");

    }
    inFile.close();
    return s;

}
```

Is there any easy solution or do I have to write another Scanner and delimiters and what not.

Comment: The trim() method should help remove any whitespace.

Comment: I don't think this actually quite works to begin with. You're throwing out everything in the file except for the last line (unless your file only has one line anyway).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Answer (score 3):

Call [`String.trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) on each read line which removes leading and trailing spaces:

```
s = inFile.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
```

You can also use [`Files.readAllLines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) to read all lines into a `List`:

```
for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName + ".txt",
                 StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    String[] words = line.trim().split(" ");
    // do something with words
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `trim()` method to remove leading and trailing whitespaces:

```
s = inFile.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
```

But, as @tnw pointed out, only the last line is taken into account in your code...

Comment: Yeah, I know, It would only grab one line, it's probably lazy but for now it only needs to grab one. @tnw

Answer (score 2):

You can use `trim()` method before splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use regular expression. If you want to save first space, do you need something like this:

```
s = inFile.nextLine().split("[^s]\\s+");
```

if you are interested, you will learn more about regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)